# Subgroups of SE(2)

Tags: group-theory

I was wondering, what are all the subgroups of SE(2)? Is it known? I know that SE(2) is the semidirect product of the plane with SO(2), but I am unsure of how to use this to compute all subgroups.

Comment: You are going to need some restrictions on the kind of subgroup you want if you expect some sort of classification.

Comment: Please, define what do you mean by "known". For instance, do you regard all subgroups of ${\mathbb R}$ as "known"?

Answer (score 1):

*Any* finite group of order $n\le 7$ can be represented by isometrics of $\Bbb R^2$, see [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=E5OjDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=classification+of+subgroups+of+Isom(R%5E2)&source=bl&ots=I8n2yMaRKI&sig=ACfU3U15kQ1_CkL7KzW-Q47L5dcytNWzYQ&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjo8Z-8-cPiAhXrpYsKHc8jD5IQ6AEwAHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=classification%20of%20subgroups%20of%20Isom(R%5E2)&f=false). Furthermore, all infinite discrete cocompact subgroups are classified, see "wallpaper groups".